# HTML to PDF conversion with iText for .NET: row size is greater than page size

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF using iText for .NET, but when i try to convert it gives me the error shown in this screen shot:

[image]

I checked thoroughly, and it's because of the row content of an HTML table that 
 exceeds the size of the page. How do I solve this problem?

Code:

```
        var pdfbody1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        pdfbody1.Append(GenerateReport());
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Work_" + lblorderNo.Text.Trim() + ".pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        var sw = new StringWriter(pdfbody1);
        var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //divexcel.RenderControl(hw);
        var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        var page = new pdfPage();


        var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3);

        //Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80f, 80f, -2f, 35f);
        var htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        var path = Server.MapPath(@"../pdf/");
        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path + "Work_" + lblorderNo.Text.Trim() + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
        pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;

        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);

        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        // Response.End();
```

Comment: You didn't share any code, but the error message in the screen shot reveals that you're using an old version of iText. You should use iText 7 to [convert HTML to PDF](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). Also note that you still use the name **iTextSharp**. That name was abandoned over two years ago in favor of **iText for .NET**. Please use the current name instead of the old one.

Comment: Additionally, `Response.Write(pdfDoc)` won't return the PDF, no matter which iText version you use. Check the stream you use to instantiate a `PdfWriter` for your `pdfDoc` to see where the document is written. Furthermore, please use text instead of screen shots to post code and stack traces. By indenting them with 4 spaces they'll be properly formatted.

Comment: I have added the code i dont have license to the itext 7 please if u guys could help me out to correct the problem in current version,if i could set allow split row this will solve the problem , i know that can be done in pdfprow since this is html conversion i dont know how to ... please any suggestions...